# Multiple returns from a single int

Tags: java, random, int

I've been trying to make a score keeping method for blackjack (oh yes there are 100's of pages of code to reference, none have the segment I'm looking for)

All I want is an int array to return, a value between 1 and 11, and then repeat it, returning a different random value.

I have tried dozens of methods, and I'm either not skilled enough to make it work, or the method doesn't suit the rest of my code.

here is what I am trying most recently.

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

class jacktest
{
    public static void main ( String[] args )
    {
            Random r = new Random();

            Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
            String name;
            boolean playing = true;
            boolean notplaying = true;
            int ncard = 1 + r.nextInt(11);

            for (i=0; i>11; ++i);

            System.out.println("two cards from the same int: "+ncard +ncard);
    }
}
```

can someone save me some torture, and explain to me, why ncard + ncard yeilds the same number on both occurances?

or what would be a better way to get the same result?

Thanks

PS: I would like the program to say something like,

```
your first card is a 8 
your second card is 4
total 12 H or S (hit or stick)
Hit: 5
Total:17 H or S (hit or stick)
S
Sticking at 17
DEALERS turn:
```

so the total is remembered, and increased depending on the `h` or `s` input.

I have seen this type of code in another program, but it doesn't fit my limited coding skills. I would need something very simple and easy to manipulate.

Comment: `ncard` is a variable that will always have the same value unless you modify it. You only set it in one place in your code. Is that the part where you're stuck?

Answer (score 1):

The way a for-statement works is that it repeats the stuff in it's block.

```
 int ncard = 1 + r.nextInt(11);
 for (i=0; i>11; ++i);  // get rid of this semicolon, the smeicolon creates a block
 System.out.println("two cards from the same int: "+ncard +ncard);
```

If it would read like this

```
 int ncard = 1 + r.nextInt(11);
 for (i=0; i>11; ++i)  // indent next line to make it look nice
     System.out.println("two cards from the same int: "+ncard +ncard);
```

Does not run at all because i is never bigger than 11. A more reasonable

```
 int ncard = 1 + r.nextInt(11);
 for (int i=0; i<11; ++i){
     System.out.println("two cards from the same int: "+ncard +ncard);
 }
```

Now to actually get a new ncard for each repetition You should do

```
 for (i=0; i<11; ++i){
     int ncard = 1 + r.nextInt(11);
     System.out.println("two cards from the same int: "+ncard +ncard);
 }
```

Now to expand on your edit if you do

```
 int card1 = 1 + r.nextInt(11);
 int card2 = 1 + r.nextInt(11);
```

You can, after those create a condition

```
 if(card1 + card2 <= 17){
     // don't hit.
 }
```

Comment: Lovely !!!!
Thanks a lot Mr.Giraffe :)

I made a PS: above, could you help me with that as well?

Comment: I don't mind if it's horrible or not :) as long as I get to sleep tonight lol. RealSkeptic edited my edit, to make it more readable. post#1

Comment: @VincentTyson You also need another variable to take care of the sum. Your program needs to repeat over the users input.

Comment: ok, I made changes to the code, and now it doesn't return anything, is this because int i=0; ??

Comment: @VincentTyson That might be a new question.

Comment: @VincentTyson ncard can only be one value. create an ncard2 if you want a second card.

Comment: ok. i'll leave it there, I'm certain I will need more help at some point, but I will try on my own for awhile and see how I go.

Comment: Frustration is a part of learning this stuff.  Your mind has a lot to get used to.  One technique is to try and mentally walk trough the program as an execution would.  The next step is to try a debugger.

Answer (score 0):

Your loop ending becauase your semicolon, and enter your random and the print in the loop:

```
class jacktest
{
    public static void main ( String[] args )
    {
            Random r = new Random();

            Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
            String name;
            boolean playing = true;
            boolean notplaying = true;


            for (i=0; i>11; ++i) {
                int ncard = 1 + r.nextInt(11);
                System.out.println("two cards from the same int: "+ncard +ncard);
            }


} }
```

Comment: Righto. I think I have enough to work with, I'll post back here with any hiccups. Thanks for the support fellas.


Cannot find symbol..... should it be

int i =ncard; ??? or something else

Comment: Where and how should I declare " i ", no matter where I put it, the code either fails completely or cannot find symbol.

Comment: I just tagged you, to repeat the question, when I use the for statement I get the error cannot find symbol i, I've tried everything I can think of , and still no joy. can you help please?

Comment: hoo my bad, you need to declare the type of i, you can do it in the for: for (int i = 0... let me know of it work

Comment: yep that compiled nicely, only the system.out.println was blank when I ran the program. There doesn't seem to be any relationship between i and nCard. I want to say int nCard = i; or something like that, am I close?

Comment: well, no... in fact both the int variables i and ncard already = something else, so I can't forge the relationship between them without a work around. going to need more coffee.... back in 15